# OpenSharedItem throws an error invalid path or url

Tags: vba, outlook, runtime-error

I am trying to import an ics file into Outlook 2016. Running on Server 2012 R2.

I got the code from --> https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/Open-the-icsical-file-49e2263c

This is my code:

```
Public Sub OpeniCal()

 'Declaration
 Dim oNamespace As NameSpace
 Dim oSharedItem As AppointmentItem

 ' Get a reference to a NameSpace object.
 Set obNamespace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")

 ' Open the iCal file containing the shared item and display it
 Set oSharedItem = obNamespace.OpenSharedItem("C:\temp\ICS\EventCalendar.ics")
 'oSharedItem.Display

 'Save the ical to your Calendar
 oSharedItem.Save

End Sub
```

When reaching the line

```
Set oSharedItem = obNamespace.OpenSharedItem("C:\temp\ICS\EventCalendar.ics")
```

I get

> Run-time error '440': Invalid path or URL.

The URL/Path is valid and file exist in the folder.

What is wrong? How can I fix this?

Edit:
I tried putting the server name in the path ("\ServerName\temp\ICS\EventCalendar.ics"), but getting same error.
[Error, Invalid Path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RfNAo.png)

Thanks

S

Comment: Try pasting this `C:\temp\ICS` in in the Run Window `Win + R` ..See if the File is there in that folder

Comment: Hi @Mikku,
Yes, it works perfectly.
The folder is opened and the file is in there.

Answer (score 0):

> Run-time error '440': Invalid path or URL.

First of all, make sure the specified file is accessible. The error means the specified string is malformed or file/folder doesn't exist.

> Running on Server 2012 R2

It is not clear whether Outlook is run manually or programmatically.

Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.

If you are building a solution that runs in a server-side context, you should try to use components that have been made safe for unattended execution. Or, you should try to find alternatives that allow at least part of the code to run client-side. If you use an Office application from a server-side solution, the application will lack many of the necessary capabilities to run successfully. Additionally, you will be taking risks with the stability of your overall solution. Read more about that in the [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/257757/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office?wa=wsignin1.0%3Fwa%3Dwsignin1.0) article.

Comment: Hi @Eugene Astafiev,
The file exist and have access.
If the string is malformed, what is the correct format then?

The solution I am trying to build is based on VBA macros that run in Outlook 2016. The office suit is installed on a server 2012r2 machine.

I will consider your recommendations, but at this stage I don't see any other options for my issue.

Cheers!
S